# Covariance $X$ and $e^{X}$

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality, covariance

How can I prove that covariance of random variable $X$ and $e^{X}$ is non-negative regardless distribution of $X$. I assume it is true.

Comment: is $E$ a positive constant?

Comment: Yes, it is actually e. Sorry for confusion

Comment: By positive, you mean non-negative (0 is allowed), right?

Comment: Non-negative is sufficient

Comment: (Well, I hope so, because it is also necessary -- there are easy examples of distributions for which it's zero)

Comment: It is true, but I have not managed to prove it this way yet.

Comment: It is not a proof but just an exploration. For $X$ being a r.v. assuming value $k$ with probability $p$ and $0$ with probability $(1-p)$, you can find that $\text{cov}(X, e^X)=p(p-1)(1-e^k) k\ge 0$ for $p\in[0,1]$ and $k \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: @samo I have solved the problem with $\frac{\gamma (1-\gamma) e^u}{\left(\gamma e^u-\gamma+1\right)^2}$ why did you delete it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{Cov}(X,e^X)&=E[Xe^X]-E[X]E[e^X]\\
&=E[Xe^X-\mu e^X]\\
&=E[(X-\mu)e^X]
\\&=E[(X-\mu)(e^X-e^{\mu})]
\end{align}
$$

The last step comes from $E[(X-\mu) c] = 0$ for any constant $c$.

Because $e^x$ is non-decreasing (this is all we need), $(x-\mu)(e^x-e^{\mu})\geq0$ $\forall x$

Hence $\operatorname{Cov}(X,e^X) \ge 0$

Comment: Is this statement that true cov($X,Y$)$>= 0$ and $f$ is non-decresing function then  cov($X,f(Y)$)$>= 0$? And where can I find it?

Comment: I have added more details in my answer

Comment: I am not sure, because here you assume that$E[e^{X}] = e^{E[X]}  $, which is not the same in general.

Comment: @Arash No, this answer is correct (+1) It never assumed $E[e^{X}] = e^{E[X]}$. I edited it for clarity.

Comment: @loenbloy, Definitely right; nice answer; +1.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Very nice answer, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are two independent and identically distributed random variables. Since $e^x$ is an increasing function, $X-Y$ and $e^{X}-e^Y$ are co-sign. So the following holds:
$$
\mathbb E[(X-Y)(e^X-e^Y)]\geq 0.
$$
Using the assumption that $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed, we have $\mathbb E(e^X)=\mathbb E(e^Y)$ and $\mathbb E(X)=\mathbb E(Y)$. Hence:
$$
\mathbb E[(X-Y)(e^X-e^Y)]=2\mathbb E(Xe^X)-2\mathbb E(X)\mathbb E(e^X)\geq 0.
$$
The last one is two times the covariance of $X$ and $e^X$.

---

The statement can be generalized for any increasing function $f$. The reverse holds for any decreasing function.